# How does manifest recognize the particular activity as a main or first activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am having four activities named as first, second, third and fourth activity. I know that Manifest is very essential file and acts as a root of the application. What I need is, instead of displaying first activity (ie. Login Activity) it should display the third activity (ie. Instruction activity) at first when I run the whole application.

So, all these four activities are founded in Manifest file. So now, how does Manifest recognize which activity should be launched first and how does it give importance to third activity (Instruction activity) that is to be launched first instead of other activities?

Then, I also have to know the concept of when it comes to multiple activities may have multiple launchers so how does this Intent filter does a filter by specifying messages that an activity listens to? By the way, how does intent filter and launcher plays a role when it comes to multiple activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`, and `Service` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` has an [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) that specifies how it interacts with the Android Environment. For example, *BroadcastReceivers* can specify what broadcast events it is listening to.

*Activities* can specify things like how they are seen in the home screen, or what files extensions can be opened in the app. Some apps don't have *Activities* or *Intent Filters* - and just use *Services* and *BroadcastReceivers*. If an app does use one or more *Activities*, the developer can optionally add the *Intent Filter* - but this is not required. If the user wants to provide a launcher for the user to be able to open the app, he or she must use this *Intent Filter*:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This will create a launcher with the application icon (or an activity icon if it is overridden with the `android:icon` attribute) and the name of the activity (specified by the `android:label` attribute). So for example, I could have a manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OtherActivity"
        android:label="@string/other_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_other_launcher" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This manifest states that there are two launcher *Activities* - `MainActivity` and `OtherActivity`. They have different icons and different names. They are also completely separate *Activity* - so each one will have to handle receiving new *intent*, just as you would any other *Activity*.

So, to answer your question - there isn't necessarily a main or first *Activity*, and there could be multiple main or first *Activities*.

Also keep in mind that *first Activity* may be configured changing an *Activity's* [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). By default each newly launched *Activity* would be a new instance of the same app - and would have separate back stacks rooted at the *Activity* that first opened via the *Intent Filter*.

Answer (score 0):

```
In side Manifest File Mention these line     inside activity for launching this activity as launcher activity
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.themap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Main activity contains these filters, depending on these filters main activity will launch at first time,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

these filters should be declared only for one activity (i.e MainActivity). If you want to show any other activities at first you need to keep some conditions in MainActivity and call those activities according to that.

Comment: It is not necessary for declaring only one activity as MAIN and LAUNCHER. With action as `android.intent.action.MAIN` it only says that this activity does not require any data to start and category `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` says that it should be shown in the Launcher.

Comment: @ManveerChawla : What do you mean "It is not necessary for declaring only one activity as MAIN and LAUNCHER"?

Comment: Theoretically you can have as many activities as you want which declare intent filter with action MAIN and category LAUNCHER. It is just that applications dont have this usecase.

Comment: @ManveerChawla if you declare Main and Launcher for every activity it create no of icons on home screen equals to no of activities you decrleared in manifest.. dont declare Main, Launcher to all the activities.

Comment: Yes it does and that is the point. It all depends on application. My point is that it is not necessary to have only one activity do that, there is no restriction from platform.

Answer (score 0):

There is a intent-filter with the action item which says this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The is what makes it the default activity!

EDIT:

There can be multiple activities with the same intent filter, each of those activities would give a new icon with the icon associated with that activity. Clicking on the icon would open up to their respective activity first.

Comment: What does category mean and how does Intent filter works  on here?

Comment: an intent filter basically specifies the messages or broadcasts that an activity listens to!

Category basically gives more information about what handles the intent! In this case 'LAUNCHER' specifies that this is the initial activity.

Comment: When your manifest is parsed, the activity with the MAIN action gets picked up as the first activity

Comment: @Meena you should also note that multiple `Activities` can have this intent filter - allowing your app to have multiple launchers.

Comment: @Phil : Yeah, when it comes to multiple activities that can have multiple launchers so how does this Intent filter does a filter by specifying messages that an activity listens to? Here, how does intent filter and launcher plays a role when it comes to multiple activities..Can you explain me clearly please?

Comment: @Meena I added an answer to cover this fully: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21871216/763080